# Найти параметр запроса в ссылке

Tags: python, парсер, url

К примеру, для адреса:

```
url = 'https://example.com/path?key=value%20?:)#fragment?not-query'
```

Получить `key`:

```
key = 'value ?:)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметр запроса можно получить, используя [`urllib.parse.parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = 'https://example.com/path?key=value%20?:)#fragment?not-query'
[key] = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['key']
print(key)  # -> value ?:)
```

Связанный вопрос: [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5074803/4279).